# Export windows logs to csv each 1 hour

Tags: powershell, csv, days

I really need your help, I already make a script for export logs to csv file:

```
Set-Variable -Name EventAgeDays -Value 1
Set-Variable -Name CompArr -Value @("Localhost")
Set-Variable -Name LogNames -Value @("Security", "Application", "System")
Set-Variable -Name EventTypes -Value @("Information", "Error", "Warning", "FailureAudit", "SuccessAudit")
Set-Variable -Name ExportFolder -Value "C:\"

$el_c = @()
$now = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($(Get-Date), [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id, 'GMT Standard Time')
$startdate=$now.adddays(-$EventAgeDays)
$ExportFile=$ExportFolder + "mx_sugus_poc_" + $now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm") + ".csv"

foreach($comp in $CompArr)
{
  foreach($log in $LogNames)
  {
    Write-Host Processing $comp\$log
    $el = get-eventlog -ComputerName $comp -log $log -After $startdate -EntryType $EventTypes -Message "*"
    $el_c += $el
  }
}

$el_sorted = $el_c | Sort-Object TimeGenerated
Write-Host Exporting to $ExportFile
$el_sorted|Select TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source, EventID, MachineName, UserName, Message | export-CSV $ExportFile -NoTypeInfo
```

Additional I change the date for a GMT format.

I want to change the search in my logs instead of every day for every hour.

Can you help me with this ???

Thanks so much !!!

Comment: What issues are you running into trying to run this hourly versus daily?

Comment: Agree with Doug, might be more to it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$startdate=$now.adddays(-$EventAgeDays)` to `$startdate=$now.addHours(-1)`